# Eclipse shows error 'The type cannot be resolved' in code lines but runs OK

Tags: java, eclipse

I have the following code, in Eclipse IDE, it shows `The type com.aspose.cells.b.a.d cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required type com.aspose.cells.Workbook` error in code lines, but there is no compile error and it runs OK.

Also, there is no any error in IntilliJIdea IDE.
[image: eclipse error]

Code:

```java
import com.aspose.cells.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        System.out.println(CellsHelper.getVersion());
        
        PdfSaveOptions pdfSaveOptions = new PdfSaveOptions();
        
        
        Workbook wb = new Workbook();
        wb.getWorksheets().get(0).getCells().get("A1").putValue("test");
        
        wb.save("test_Java.pdf");
        
        wb.save("testWithOptions_Java.pdf", pdfSaveOptions);
    }

}
```

Please note, [`aspose-cells-23.3.jar`](https://releases.aspose.com/java/repo/com/aspose/aspose-cells/23.3/aspose-cells-23.3.jar) is needed for the above code.
Maybe there is something wrong in the used jar. However, I want to know why the error is dispalyed in Eclipse, but the code runs OK? Which item in the jar causes the error?

Comment: How is the project managing dependencies? Maven? Gradle? Something else? Show whatever is used to declare dependencies (eg, if Maven, show the pom file).

Comment: @E-Riz I just dowloaded the jar `aspose-cells-23.3.jar`, and add it to the buid path.

Answer (score 0):

It seems an issue with Eclipse to show hint for grammar check. We think the issue is caused by the fact that there are some classes with same name with their package. Such structure is obviously allowed by Java itself but not for Eclipse.

As it does not affect the execution of Java application so you may continue to use it without any issue. But, since it might cause a little confusion/inconvenience for some users, so we have decided to change the mechanism of generating the Jar a bit to avoid such kind of issue or situation. This enhancement will be incorporated in our next (upcoming) release/version: Aspose.Cells for Java v23.4.

Hope, this helps a bit.

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.